# Unknown letter ℑ used in an equation

Tags: notation, complex-numbers

I need to write by hand the equation from the attached snapshot but I really don't know what letter is that seen in the front of square brackets `[` . Can anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: This isn't really the kind of questions we answer here but [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can often help, since the LaTeX command to write a symbol usually has a somewhat telling name (in this case \Im, meaning "the imaginary part of"). You might have guessed that from the equation itself based on [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). Actually, I just read the last part of the accompanying text and it says so there as well, so now I'm confused as to why you asked...

Comment: This is a variant of a Fraktur-typeface *J*, i.e. $\mathfrak{J}$ (edit: it's a J, not I), which is used for the *imaginary part* of the complex number, also commonly denoted $\mathrm{Im}$, and contrasted to the *real part* $\mathfrak{R}$ or $\mathrm{Re}$, etc.

Comment: This question is about typesetting and so would be appropriate for our sister site [LaTeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I didn't know about LaTeX or Detexify. Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typesetting.

Comment: This is question about physics (specificaly about notation used in physics), it would be good if some people would kindly allow other people to access this site and ask such a relevant question. if i were the OP and knew about this site i would consider it natural to ask such a question, someone disagrees with this?

Comment: @NikosM. As Wouter's comment shows, the question also does not meet the expected effort requirement.

Comment: @Danu, well this pre-supposes that one knows where to search and for what (at least). So i would say it is not generaklly applicable in this form

Comment: @NikosM. Perhaps not - but in this instance the answer is literally *right there*.

Comment: @Danu, i see what you mean, still if someone could make this connection (due to other knowledge), i think would not bother wait 2 hours to get this simple answer.

Comment: I agree that questions about notation in physics are on-topic questions about physics. Having to invent your own name or mental model for an unfamiliar symbol is an extra cognitive load that impedes physical understanding — I remember being absent the day that my freshman professor mentioned that $\varkappa$ was a kappa, and spending the next lecture(s?) feeling too stupid to ask what that x-thing was and where was the $\kappa$ that everyone talked about. Detexify looks wonderful, but even if one has heard of it (I haven't apart from ads on phys.SE, and I mostly ignore ads) it isn't foolproof.

Comment: It's on topic if the question is about the meaning of that symbol. But the question appears to be about calligraphy: "*I must to write by hand the equation from the attached snapshot ...*" If that's the case, that would make the question off topic.

Comment: If OP is asking what a notation means, then it is on-topic according to [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/2451) meta post. On the other hand, if OP is asking what is the LaTeX command to produce a character or symbol, then it seems off-topic.

Comment: The real question is why a student is being forced to use a textbook that makes use of notation that is both obscure and obsolete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is notation for the imaginary part of a complex number. It is a [fraktur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) letter `I`, and its counterpart for the real part is a fraktur letter `R`. Thus, if $z=x+iy$ and $x,y$ are real, one writes
$$
\mathfrak{R}\,z=x\ \ \text{ and }\ \ \mathfrak{I}\,z=y.
$$
A good chart of the fraktur alphabet is in [this Yale resource](http://www.library.yale.edu/cataloging/music/fraktur.htm), which includes handwriting guidance, though some variation can be seen in [google image searches](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fraktur+handwriting&tbm=isch). In LaTeX the quickest way to produce this is as the defaults of the commands `\Re` and `\Im` (though it is common for people to change this default), and which produce $\Re$ and $\Im$. Alternatively, you can use `\mathfrak{R}` and `\mathfrak{I}`, which produce $\mathfrak{R}$ and $\mathfrak{I}$; these are similar in the MathJax font displayed here but the specifics can vary on different systems.

In my experience this is an older notation which has been superseded, pretty much everywhere, by the uppercase combinations $\mathrm{Re}$ and $\mathrm{Im}$:
$$
\operatorname{Re}(z)=x\ \ \text{ and }\ \ \operatorname{Im}(z)=y.
$$
These are typeset using `\operatorname{Re}` and `\operatorname{Im}`, although `\mathrm` usually works equally well. In handwritten work, most people denote the real and imaginary parts in this way; if you are making notes on a book which has the old notation, it is perfectly OK to use the new one, and it will not cause confusion for anyone reading your notes.

One thing to note is that fraktur is not a completely fixed font; it is more of a style of handwriting and there is a fair bit of variation in how each particular letter is drawn in different sources (for a sample, see [the google images results for 'fraktur'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fraktur&tbm=isch)). The particular $\mathfrak{I}$ in your image is relatively similar to how some fraktur fonts display the `J` (which sort of looks like $\mathfrak{J}$, but see the image results for the variation), but that is more of a fluke. The correct character to use is the `I`.

Comment: How to write it by hand using a pen or a pencil?

Comment: @PratyayGhosh See edit. If you feel this is unclear or not useful - or otherwise worthy of a downvote - I would appreciate hearing your reasoning.

Comment: I feel your content not relevant.

Comment: Well, then have a good day.

Comment: I am having a good day.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but this is not correct. While `\mathfrak I`, `\mathfrak J` and `\Im` appear to be very similar in mathjax (to wit: `\mathfrak I`: $\mathfrak I$, `\mathfrak J`: $\mathfrak J$, `\Im`: $\Im$), they are not the same using the TeXLive distribution. You don't even need the mathfrak font to use `\Im`. It's a part of basic LaTeX, provided by fontmath.ltx.

Comment: @PratyayGhosh -- How to write it by hand? Simple: Use `Im`. That's a whole lot easier to write than is the fraktur character $\Im$, and `Im` says exactly what the intent is.

Comment: +1 based on the last edit. Oh yes, and have a good day, Emilio!

Comment: BTW, here's the definition of `\Im` in LaTeX, from fontmath.ltx: `\DeclareMathSymbol{\Im}{\mathord}{symbols}{"3D}`. The macro `\Im` that generates the symbol $\Im$ predates LaTeX. Lamport simply redefined the TeX macro with the same name to make it more LaTeX-like. The macro `\Im` is defined in plain.tex as `\mathchardef\Im="023D`. Knuth apparently liked that symbol!

Comment: Hmmm. So what's the `"023D`? Unicode?

Comment: @David I have already wrote that in a answer here. I don't understand why people are so concerned about writing it in Latex. The questioner wanted to write it by hand.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - "023D is not unicode. It comes from the original TeX written by Donald Knuth in the 1960s. I know TeX well enough to know why I have to `\expandafter` before something. I even know why I sometimes have to `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter` before something, and sometimes have to add some more `\expandafter` macros afterwards. I even know when it's time to `\relax`! But that charcode stuff? That's deep magic. I read "<blah> as "<deep_TeX_magic_of_which_I_am_still_ignorant>.

Comment: @David I did find [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192696/13423) with at least some logic behind it.

Comment: @Emilio - I found that answer, too. That charcode stuff is still black magic to me. Try to understand what [xii.tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105808/how-could-the-macro-xii-tex-be-simplified-into-a-better-readable-form) does. If you can, you're a much better LaTeX author than am I. If you can't you can join me as a [LaTeX cargo cult programmer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20094/im-a-cargo-cult-programmer).

Comment: +1 a) for the effort and explanation which learned me a lot, b) for the desicion to answer this question which some almost had it off-topic

Answer (score 2):

If it is actually the imaginary part of a complex variable, then just write $Im[\cdot]$ instrade of the curly character.

Comment: I don't see how this is helpful. We now use the upright form $\operatorname{Im}$, but one cannot simply ignore a prevalent old notation simply because one doesn't like it much. -1.

Comment: I never said to ignore it depending on the liking. Numlock wanted to write it by hand. What do you suggest him? Use a calligraphy pen whenever he want to write imaginary part of a complex variable.

Comment: No, I suggest that the OP write $\operatorname{Im}$ in their own work, but this will not help them make sense of older texts that do use the $\Im$ notation, which is the question at hand. Unless, of course, you're suggesting that the OP scratch out all occurrences of $\Im$ and scribble $\operatorname{Im}$ on top, or that all old books be reprinted and replaced, with the new notation in place.

Comment: read the first line.